# Como resolver erro na impressão de strings?

Tags: c, string, struct, char, printf

Estou passando uma struct por referencia para uma função na hora de inserir os dados, e novamente na hora de imprimir esses dados.Porém a função "Insere_elemento" não lê o float do tempo (ele pula a leitura), e a função "Imprime_dados" não imprime as strings na tela apenas os ints e floats.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct pessoa{
    char *nome;
    int idade;
    float salario;
    char *cargo;
    float tempo;

} PESSOA;
void Insere_elemento(PESSOA*dados);
void Imprime_dados(PESSOA*dados);
int main ()
{
    PESSOA dados;
    Insere_elemento(&dados);
    Imprime_dados(&dados);

    return 0;


}
void Insere_elemento(PESSOA*dados)
{
    char aux_nome[20];
    char aux_cargo[20];
    scanf("%[^\n]", aux_nome);
    dados->nome=aux_nome;
    __fpurge(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &dados->idade);
    scanf("%f", &dados->salario);
    scanf("%[^\n]", aux_cargo);
    dados->cargo=aux_cargo;
    __fpurge(stdin);
    scanf("%f", &dados->tempo);

}
void Imprime_dados(PESSOA*dados)
{
printf("%s \n", dados->nome);
printf("%d \n", dados->idade);
printf("%2.f \n", dados->salario);
printf("%s \n", dados->cargo);
printf("%2.f \n", dados->tempo);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se souber controlar as leituras e a forma como elas funcionam não precisa de `__fpurge` nem semelhantes.

No caso acontece que a leitura com `%[^\n]` não funciona se a primeira coisa que está na entrada já é um `\n` deixado por um previo `%d` ou `%f` por exemplo. Tem inumeras formas de contornar este problema mas a mais simples é colocar um espaço antes do `%[^\n]` para consumir a quebra anterior.

Também está errada a utilização que está a fazer dos `char*`, esta:

```
void Insere_elemento(PESSOA*dados) {
    char aux_nome[20];
    scanf("%[^\n]", aux_nome);
    dados->nome=aux_nome;
    ...
```

Está errado pois a string para o nome foi alocada na função em *stack* e quando esta terminar o espaço vai ficar marcado como livre e por isso qualquer acesso que faça depois representa comportamento indefinido. A solução é alocar os carateres diretamenete com [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) e depois fazer a leitura para o espaço alocado.

Exemplo:

```
void Insere_elemento(PESSOA*dados) {
    dados->nome = malloc(20 * sizeof(char)); //alocação com malloc
    dados->cargo = malloc(20 * sizeof(char)); //alocação com malloc
    scanf("%[^\n]19s", dados->nome);
    scanf("%d", &dados->idade);
    scanf("%f", &dados->salario);
    scanf(" %[^\n]19s", dados->cargo);
    //     ^-- espaço consome a quebra anterior
    scanf("%f", &dados->tempo);
}
```

De notar que a escrita que está a fazer em `Imprime_dados` tem o formatador `%2.f` quando provavelmente você queria `%.2f`

[Veja o exemplo que dei a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/NqlOsf)

Repare também que forcei o tamanho máximo na leitura com `scanf` para 19 a fim de  evitar possíveis problemas com *buffer overflow*.